# Will apt-get remove mysql-server-5.1 delete /var/lib/mysql?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apt

I installed mysql 5.5 in /usr/local/mysql . If I apt-get remove the old package, it won't delete the data directory in /var/lib/mysql will it?

UPDATE: Yes it's an official standard generic Ubuntu package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one way to know for certain is to inspect the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.1.postrm` script.  Without knowing if you are using the official package, or which version of the package, I cannot say with certainty what will happen.

Typically a `apt-get remove` will not purge any data or configuration scripts.  If you want everything to be removed you use `apt-get purge`.

But why chance it?  Make a backup first, and then remove.

Comment: I seem rm -rf /var/lib/mysql in a block conditional on `if [ "$1" = "purge" -a ! \( -x /usr/sbin/mysqld -o -L /usr/sbin/mysqld \) ]; the
n`

Comment: I believe it's intended to remove /var/lib/mysql on purge, but in actual fact it doesn't:

http://serverfault.com/questions/369773/completely-remove-mysql-server-from-ubuntu#comment376369_369773

I can verify that a purge doesn't actually remove the directory in Ubuntu 12.04, MySQL 5.5.