# completely remove mysql-server from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-11.10

I want to completely remove and re-install mysql on Ubuntu 11.10. I've tried removing it by running:

```
apt-get remove --purge 'mysql-.*'
```

But when I re-install it, the old databases are still there, so it obviously wasn't completely removes. How do I remove:

- the server
- databases
- configuration files

Comment: removing packages won't remove your databases, you will need to delete them manually. You can find database files in /var/lib/mysql

Comment: @DmitryAlexeyev, I beg to differ the purge code in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.1.postrm` clearly has a block of code in place that should be removing `/var/lib/mysql` if the purge executed properly.

Comment: @Zoredache You are correct; however, the logic in that script is bad. It only removes (with prompting) `/var/lib/mysql` if `/usr/sbin/mysqld` if it isn't executable. Alas, that file is provided by mysql-server-core-5.1. Because mysql-server-5.1 depends on mysql-server-core-5.1, during a removal mysql-server-5.1 is removed first; thus `/usr/sbin/mysqld` will still exist and the data directory won't be removed. (Verified by running `dpkg --force-depends --purge mysql-server-core-5.1` and then `dkg --force-depends --purge mysql-server-5.1`. N.B. this is not a solution to the question.)

Answer (score 3):

Delete the default MySQL data directory is */var/lib/mysql*. And finally delete the configuration directory that resides in */etc/mysql*.

Reinstall and you should be good to go!

Comment: oh, is that an ubuntu packaging thing?, I have the mysql configuration file as /etc/my.cnf

Comment: Although the paths might vary a little bit, the general thumb rule is configuration lies inside /etc.